# Invalid key provided to SecureStore

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am getting the following error

> Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Invalid key provided to SecureStore. Keys must not be empty and contain only alphanumeric characters, ".", "-", and "_".

My code:

```
function onpresscard(item) {
    const lang = item.code;
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`mechphone`)
      .add({
        phonenumber: phonenumber,
      })
      .then((docRef) => {
        const id = docRef.id;
        const pid = phonenumber+'id';
        const langcode = phonenumber+'lang';
        save(pid, langcode, id, lang);
      }).then(()=>{
        navigation.replace("AppNavigator");
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      });
  }

async function save(pid, langcode, id, lang) {
    console.log(pid, langcode, id, lang, "inside saveid");

    try {
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(pid, id);
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(langcode, lang);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

onpresscard function is invoked on a button click. I'm getting the expected value docRef.id and able to pass the value to save function with the following parameter. Again its received in the save function and
console.log(pid, langcode, id, lang, "inside saveid") clearly shows the value which is alphanumerical and not empty.

How to avoid this error?

I am using expo react native - Android emulator

Comment: Can you show the output from your console.log?

Comment: Oh my bad. I did not notice + symbol from the phone number. Now its working after providing proper alphanumeric key. Thanks for your reply.